# Running python scripts in their directory with Notepad++

Tags: windows, command-line, python, notepad++, cmd.exe

I am trying to get a run command set up in Notepad++ that will run the python file I have open in NP++ with the current_directory set to the folder containing the open script.  It is not working, and I have hit a point where I can't figure out why.

I can get the run command to open CMD and change the directory appropriately with the following:

```
cmd /K cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
```

This works as I expect, CMD open in the current directory, waiting for a command.  I can type python in here and python starts in this cmd window!

I expect the following run command to do what the previous one did, then run python in the CMD window:

```
cmd /K cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" python
```

But this does not work, it gives the error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening / what I must do instead to get python to run here?

Comment: `cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" python` is an invalid command. Try chaining them `cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python`

Comment: You are my new favourite human!

Comment: I wrote an answer (so it can be accepted) as comments are ephemeral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Does anyone know why this would be happening / what I must do instead?

> cmd /K cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" python

The above is an invalid command.

You should instead run the two commands sequentially using the `&` operator

```
cmd /K cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python
```

> `commandA & commandB`
>
> Run `commandA` and then run `commandB`

Source [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)